# JQuery - Textbox focusout event needs to be handled on a button click before click event handler handled

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is focus-out event handler for a text-box and a submit button to post a form data.

Focus-out event handler having a ajax service call where validating text-box value. 
My scenario is that entered a value in text-box(text-box is focused now) and making a click event. While making click event, text-box focus-out must be handled first and then click event handler must be handled.

How to ensure to **run focus-out before button click event handler on a button click in JQuery**?

Comment: can you please provide your code....it will make your question more understandable

Comment: you can have an **blur** event listener on your textbox and make and ajax call over their... and within the same function function **before making ajax call disable your submit button** and **enable the button  on success callback of ajax request**

Hope you got this...